# issues in spinner Android?

Tags: android, spinner

Hai i developed a application in android,in my application i used a dynamically created spinner(many spinner),the width in 320

**problem**

when 1 spinner text is like`"aaaa",`2 spinner text is like `"a".`the two spinner width is varied.i need the  same width in all spinner.how to do?Anybody kindly solve my problem.

```
 Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: please put whole code here so we can get better solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create the spinner in XML layout with the width value and set visibility "GONE".
When you have to use it, you can retrieve it by using findviewbyid method and then you have to set the visibility at VISIBLE.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViweById(R.id.spinnerInvisible);
ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Not the solution of the above problem.nothing related with that problem..........(:

Answer (score 2):

you need to set width attribute of the spinner.I think it is "set to wrap content".You should provide width in dp.Foe ex-100dp

```
LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);        
    yourspinner.setLayoutParams(params);
```

you can also give height and width in DP. Check this method.